# Login after first installation

Tags: login, password, 21.04

I've installed the latest version of Ubuntu and set a username and password, which I confirmed too.
After installation only my computer user is shown for login, not the user I've set during installation.
But what is the password for this user? Is there a default password for that?

My alternative is to click on "not listed?" to enter my created username and password, but it says always "incorrect, please try again".

There's no type mismatch, seems like it doesn't know the user I've created or the password?

What can I do to log into Ubuntu desktop first time?

Thanks

EDIT: attached Login image
[image: login window]

Comment: is the language single?

Comment: There is no default or "my computer" user created during a real Ubuntu Desktop install on bare metal. Are you sure you installed Ubuntu Desktop instead of some other version or some other distro? What exact release of Ubuntu did you install? Can you add a picture of the login screen showing this mystery user?

Comment: What do you mean by "only my computer user is shown for login" ?

Comment: Thanks for your answers and sorry for the late response. I attached a screenshot in my post above. There you can see the name ubuntu shows on startup. It's my name but I never entered it in any field during installation. While it is a test installation I used "anonymous" as username. But both names failed by using the pw I created during installation.

Comment: So when you go through the installation, when you are at the user creation screen, (atleast 18.04 and later) you will have options like: Fullname, PC Name, User, password, retype password. IF you put your name in the fullname text box, than that's the name that it'll show when you go to login, you will be logging in as the username you had created, but for the login screen it's going to show the name you put into "full name" during the installation.

Comment: Yes, I typed in "anonymous" in the field username and password in the fields password and re-type password. Was all correct during the installation. I found out that my problem is not an unknown problem, some people before are affected, but I found no solution for me since now.

Comment: "It's my name but I never entered it in any field during installation" that seems a bit...unlikely. how could it know your name if you never entered it? note that it asks for both your real name and a username during setup. The most likely cause is that you forgot the password you entered. you can reset the password using methods described on this site.

Comment: how to reset password: https://askubuntu.com/q/24006/243321

Comment: @OrganicMarble that helped, thanks!